# Vue Cli 3 Typescript. Cannot import css/sass to the <script> block

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js, typescript2.0, vue-cli

I built new vue app with typescript using Vue Cli 3.

When I try to import css or sass to my typescript file:

> import * as sassStyles from '@/assets/sass/my.module.scss';

I got followning error:

> Cannot find module

I found this article [How to use CSS Modules with TypeScript and webpack](https://medium.com/@sapegin/css-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack-6b221ebe5f10) but I have no idea how to integrate it with Vue Cli 3 who is abstracting away webpack config.

Any idea what to put in vue.config.js to able to import css and sass files directly to  block?

I need to use `typings-for-css-modules-loader` instead of `css-loader`.

Answer (score 4):

Importing the file itself (i.e., `import '@/foo.scss'`) will automatically apply the styles to the current component, so you don't actually need a reference to the imported styles. That is:

```
// import * as sassStyles from '@/assets/sass/my.module.scss'; // DON'T DO THIS
import '@/assets/sass/my.module.scss';
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/woyj893p1l)

The only steps needed to add support for importing Sass files in a `vue-cli` project is to install [`sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) and [`sass-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader) (no additional config needed):

```
npm i -S sass sass-loader
```

Then, you could use either of the following methods to import a `.scss` file:

- *<script> import:*

```html
<script>
  import '/path/to/foo.scss';
</script>
```

- *<style src>:*

```html
<style scoped src="/path/to/foo.scss" lang="scss"></style>
```

Note the optional [`scoped`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html) attribute makes the styles apply to the current component only (like CSS Modules).

Answer (score 3):

Create a file in your project, say `ambient.d.ts` (my convention but you can call it anything), with the following:

```
declare module "@/assets/sass/*.scss" {
  const styles: any;
  export = styles;
}

declare module "@/assets/css/*.css" {
  const styles: any;
  export = styles;
}
```

adjust the type and form of the export to best match your usage.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a new file called `vue.config.js` in your project root directory.

In the file, add the following contents:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        includePaths: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'PATH_TO_WHERE_YOUR_SCSS_FILES_ARE'),
        ],
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I came across a similar problem when I was trying to import the scss files from `@material`, which located in `node_modules/@material`, after two days of digging, I found this Github [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1090) and gave it a try, and I used `'node_modules'` as `PATH_TO_WHERE_YOUR_SCSS_FILES_ARE` and it solved my problem.